# Fill background of svg in the center and not at the borders

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following svg based on the JavaScript fontawesome icon. I created a black background using `<rect fill="black"/>` so that the letters "JS" are displayed in black. This works, but the black background fill extends above and below the actual icon.

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" viewBox="0 0 448 512" style="height:1em;width:0.88em;vertical-align:-0.125em;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;font-size:inherit;fill:yellow;overflow:visible;position:relative;">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>  
  <path d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM243.8 381.4c0 43.6-25.6 63.5-62.9 63.5-33.7 0-53.2-17.4-63.2-38.5l34.3-20.7c6.6 11.7 12.6 21.6 27.1 21.6 13.8 0 22.6-5.4 22.6-26.5V237.7h42.1v143.7zm99.6 63.5c-39.1 0-64.4-18.6-76.7-43l34.3-19.8c9 14.7 20.8 25.6 41.5 25.6 17.4 0 28.6-8.7 28.6-20.8 0-14.4-11.4-19.5-30.7-28l-10.5-4.5c-30.4-12.9-50.5-29.2-50.5-63.5 0-31.6 24.1-55.6 61.6-55.6 26.8 0 46 9.3 59.8 33.7L368 290c-7.2-12.9-15-18-27.1-18-12.3 0-20.1 7.8-20.1 18 0 12.6 7.8 17.7 25.9 25.6l10.5 4.5c35.8 15.3 55.9 31 55.9 66.2 0 37.8-29.8 58.6-69.7 58.6z"/>
</svg>
```

Changing the `height` to `90%` helps to get rid of the background at the bottom, but how can I center the background fill so that it is not visible above the icon?

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" viewBox="0 0 448 512" style="height:1em;width:0.88em;vertical-align:-0.125em;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;font-size:inherit;fill:yellow;overflow:visible;position:relative;">
  <rect width="100%" height="90%" fill="black"/>  
  <path d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM243.8 381.4c0 43.6-25.6 63.5-62.9 63.5-33.7 0-53.2-17.4-63.2-38.5l34.3-20.7c6.6 11.7 12.6 21.6 27.1 21.6 13.8 0 22.6-5.4 22.6-26.5V237.7h42.1v143.7zm99.6 63.5c-39.1 0-64.4-18.6-76.7-43l34.3-19.8c9 14.7 20.8 25.6 41.5 25.6 17.4 0 28.6-8.7 28.6-20.8 0-14.4-11.4-19.5-30.7-28l-10.5-4.5c-30.4-12.9-50.5-29.2-50.5-63.5 0-31.6 24.1-55.6 61.6-55.6 26.8 0 46 9.3 59.8 33.7L368 290c-7.2-12.9-15-18-27.1-18-12.3 0-20.1 7.8-20.1 18 0 12.6 7.8 17.7 25.9 25.6l10.5 4.5c35.8 15.3 55.9 31 55.9 66.2 0 37.8-29.8 58.6-69.7 58.6z"/>
</svg>
```

I tried using classical css `style="fill:black;padding-top:5px"` but that is not working.

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" viewBox="0 0 448 512" style="height:1em;width:0.88em;vertical-align:-0.125em;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;font-size:inherit;fill:yellow;overflow:visible;position:relative;">
  <rect width="100%" height="90%" style="fill:black;padding-top:5px"/>  
  <path d="M400 32H48C21.5 32 0 53.5 0 80v352c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V80c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zM243.8 381.4c0 43.6-25.6 63.5-62.9 63.5-33.7 0-53.2-17.4-63.2-38.5l34.3-20.7c6.6 11.7 12.6 21.6 27.1 21.6 13.8 0 22.6-5.4 22.6-26.5V237.7h42.1v143.7zm99.6 63.5c-39.1 0-64.4-18.6-76.7-43l34.3-19.8c9 14.7 20.8 25.6 41.5 25.6 17.4 0 28.6-8.7 28.6-20.8 0-14.4-11.4-19.5-30.7-28l-10.5-4.5c-30.4-12.9-50.5-29.2-50.5-63.5 0-31.6 24.1-55.6 61.6-55.6 26.8 0 46 9.3 59.8 33.7L368 290c-7.2-12.9-15-18-27.1-18-12.3 0-20.1 7.8-20.1 18 0 12.6 7.8 17.7 25.9 25.6l10.5 4.5c35.8 15.3 55.9 31 55.9 66.2 0 37.8-29.8 58.6-69.7 58.6z"/>
</svg>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You will need to change the viewBox to `viewBox="0 32 448 448"`. Also add y="32" to the black rect. Otherwise y defaults to 0 You will still see the rect behind the rounded corners. To fix this you will need to add  rx="50" to the black rect. The new viewBox value is using position and the size of the bounding box of the JS path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Briefly*

The JS icon code uses one combined path for both the yellow background with round edges and the `JS` letters.

[image]

Therefore, it is impossible to paint one path with different colors: yellow for the background and black for the letters **JS** without an additional black rectangle.

***Solution:***
#1. Using a vector editor, you need to remove the outer outline of the background and leave path only for letters.

[image]

[image]

#2. Paint the path for the letters black and add a yellow background with rounded corners.

`<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow" rx="50px" />`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20%" height="20%" aria-hidden="true"   viewBox="0 0 448 512">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow" rx="60px" />
   <path d="M243.8 381.4c0 43.6-25.6 63.5-62.9 63.5-33.7 0-53.2-17.4-63.2-38.5l34.3-20.7c6.6 11.7 12.6 21.6 27.1 21.6 13.8 0 22.6-5.4 22.6-26.5V237.7h42.1zm99.6 63.5c-39.1 0-64.4-18.6-76.7-43l34.3-19.8c9 14.7 20.8 25.6 41.5 25.6 17.4 0 28.6-8.7 28.6-20.8 0-14.4-11.4-19.5-30.7-28l-10.5-4.5c-30.4-12.9-50.5-29.2-50.5-63.5 0-31.6 24.1-55.6 61.6-55.6 26.8 0 46 9.3 59.8 33.7L368 290c-7.2-12.9-15-18-27.1-18-12.3 0-20.1 7.8-20.1 18 0 12.6 7.8 17.7 25.9 25.6l10.5 4.5c35.8 15.3 55.9 31 55.9 66.2 0 37.8-29.8 58.6-69.7 58.6z"/>
   </svg>
```

*Variant with fixed icon sizes 32x32px*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" aria-hidden="true"   viewBox="0 0 448 512">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow" rx="50px" />
   <path d="M243.8 381.4c0 43.6-25.6 63.5-62.9 63.5-33.7 0-53.2-17.4-63.2-38.5l34.3-20.7c6.6 11.7 12.6 21.6 27.1 21.6 13.8 0 22.6-5.4 22.6-26.5V237.7h42.1zm99.6 63.5c-39.1 0-64.4-18.6-76.7-43l34.3-19.8c9 14.7 20.8 25.6 41.5 25.6 17.4 0 28.6-8.7 28.6-20.8 0-14.4-11.4-19.5-30.7-28l-10.5-4.5c-30.4-12.9-50.5-29.2-50.5-63.5 0-31.6 24.1-55.6 61.6-55.6 26.8 0 46 9.3 59.8 33.7L368 290c-7.2-12.9-15-18-27.1-18-12.3 0-20.1 7.8-20.1 18 0 12.6 7.8 17.7 25.9 25.6l10.5 4.5c35.8 15.3 55.9 31 55.9 66.2 0 37.8-29.8 58.6-69.7 58.6z"/>
   </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I accepted Dannys answer, since it was a bit simpler for my purpose.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, I totally wasn't aware of the details here.

Answer (score 2):

You are using 620 Bytes in a `<path>` to draw a yellow rectangle with 2 shapes cut out,
and then you add a rectangle to color those shapes

You could also change that whole SVG to:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="width:180px">
  <rect rx="4" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="yellow"/>
  <text x=10 y=28 font-family="arial" font-weight="bold">JS</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, this simplifies things a lot!